# What is the correct way to make Maven find the parent POM of my project?

Tags: maven, repository, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have a Maven project which is a part of a large scale enterprise system. I have not developed this project, but I have developed a small framework, which I am supposed to test, integrated with it. Upon copying, building and installing the project, it compiled, and I was able to launch it. However, after trying to add my framework (parent pom + 3 modules), I may have changed some settings, and now I am having trouble building the project. I have spent a lot of time trying to break down the problem, but all I have been able to do, is produce different errors, that I understand even less of.

I can't seem to find out where I can tell maven where to look for the parent POM. I have tried both the pom.xml, and settings.xml, but I haven't found any good options. I have also tried to change less obvious parameters, like changing localRepository, or adding repositories, but they proved ineffective

Here is my error message, interlaced with my attempts to fix it:

```
C:\development\my-main\customer-webpart>mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

This is my domain. this includes the master pom of this project, although it is still part of a bigger system, and not the root. I would like to build, install and run this project, to test my framework. My framework is added as a dependency in the pom.xml.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://my-server:8080/archiva/repository/my-repository//
org/myportal/client-product/0.0/client-product-0.0.pom
```

I do not know where this archiva repository is defined. It is not in the pom.xml, or settings.xml. It seems to have an error with the double /, but the client-product-0.0.pom should not be retrieved from here anyway. It is located at *C:/mavenLocalRepository/my-main/client-product/0.0/client-product-0.0.pom*

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/myportal/
client-product/0.0/client-product-0.0.pom
```

This was also the wrong location to look for the .pom-file... so then the rest of the error is produced:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: null:customer-webpart:zip:${org.myportal.version}

Reason: Cannot find parent: org.myportal:client-product for project: null:customer-webpart:zip:${org.myportal.version} for project null:customer-webpart:zip:${org.myportal.version}


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Cannot find parent: org.myportal:client-product for project: null:customer-webpart:zip:${org.myportal.version} for project null:customer-webpart:zip:${org.myportal.version}

        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:378)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:292)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:287)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Cannot find parent: org.myportal:client-product for
project: null:customer-webpart:zip:${org.myportal.version} for project null:customer-webpart:zip:${org.myportal.version}
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1370)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:821)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.ja
va:506)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:198)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProject(DefaultMaven.java:583)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:461)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:365)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: POM 'org.myportal:client-product' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.myportal:client-product:pom:0.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  my-repository (http://my-server:8080/archiva/repository/my-repository/),
  localRepository2 (C:/mavenLocalRepository/logging-framework/),
  localRepository (C:/mavenLocalRepository/my-main/),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
 for project org.myportal:client-product
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:6
03)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1366)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.myportal:client-product:pom:0.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  my-repository (http://my-server:8080/archiva/repository/my-repository/),
  localRepository2 (C:/mavenLocalRepository/logging-framework/),
  localRepository (C:/mavenLocalRepository/my-main/),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:74)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:5
56)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:331)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:200)
        ... 20 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 28 11:15:40 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/61M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\development\my-main\customer-webpart>
```

Also, this Eclipse-warning is given on my parent-tag of pom.xml for the project:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.myportal:client-product:pom:0.0 from http://my-server:8080/archiva/repository/my-repository/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
 interval of my-repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.myportal:client-product:pom:0.0 from/to my-repository (http://my-server:8080/archiva/repository/my-repository/): Failed to transfer http://my-server:8080/archiva/repository/my-repository/org/myportal/client-product/0.0/client-product-0.0.pom. Error code 307, Temporarily Moved for Domain Name Expansion and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

...and I have tried three different approaches to the parent.relativePath. 1. None at all (no tag present), 2. Empty tag (suggested at another post here) 3. tag with full path of the .pom file.

**POM.XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-product</artifactId>
        <version>0.0</version>
        <relativePath>C:\mavenLocalRepository\my-main\org\myportal\client-product\0.0\client-product-0.0.pom</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-webpart</artifactId>
    <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
    <name>my-webpart</name>
    <packaging>zip</packaging>
    <description>
        customer webpart
    </description>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        <org.logging.framework.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</org.logging.framework.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>unzip-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org.unzip.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unzip</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <groupId>org.workflow</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>workflow-framework</artifactId>
                                    <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.pdpart</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <target>src/java/generated/common-pdparts</target>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>myportal-portletframework</artifactId>
                                    <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.pdpart</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <target>src/java/generated/common-pdparts</target>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>descriptorloader-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org.descriptorloader.plugin.version2}</version>
                <executions> 
                    <execution>
                        <id>vdoclet-java-clean</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>src/java</source>
                            <target>src/java</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>vdoclet-java</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>vdoclet</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>src/java</source>
                            <target>src/java</target>
                            <template>portletdescriptor/Control.vm</template>
                            <report>target/java-conversion.txt</report>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>vdoclet-jsp-clean</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>src/java</source>
                            <target>src/webapp</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>vdoclet-jsp</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>vdoclet</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>src/java</source>
                            <target>src/webapp</target>
                            <template>portletdescriptor/JspControl.vm</template>
                            <report>target/jsp-conversion.txt</report>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.main</groupId>
                        <artifactId>main-build-dependencies</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.main.version}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>zip-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org.zip.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <fileSets>
                        <fileSet>
                            <directory>src/webapp</directory>
                        </fileSet>
                        <fileSet>
                            <directory>target/classes</directory>
                            <outputDirectory>WEB-INF/classes/</outputDirectory>
                        </fileSet>
                    </fileSets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Clean generated diretory -->
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/generated/**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-client</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-portletdomain</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>effect-client</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>mycase-client</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>mycase-portletdomain</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- myportal -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysecondportal-common</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysecondportal-webpartcommon</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>host-types</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-framework</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${library.commons.fileupload.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- external -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>faceless</groupId>
            <artifactId>bfopdf</artifactId>
            <version>0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- main -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.main</groupId>
                <artifactId>main-assemble-ear</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
            <version>${org.main.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-webdelegate</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>myportal-portletframework</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myshare</groupId>
            <artifactId>myshare-common</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myshare.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.myshare</groupId>
            <artifactId>myshare-webpartcommon</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myshare.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>docflow-client</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>docflow-webdao</artifactId>
            <version>${org.myportal.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.esb.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging-framework</artifactId>
            <version>${org.logging.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>localRepository</id>
            <url>C:/mavenLocalRepository/my-main/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>localRepository2</id>
            <url>C:/mavenLocalRepository/logging-framework/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**parent (client-product-0.0.pom):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"> 
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-version-pom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.product</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-product</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>0.0</version>
  <name>my-product  ${project.version} (old root-pom, now child of ${parent.artifactId})</name>

  <modules>
    <module>my-foundation-pom</module>
    <module>pb-product-pom</module>    
  </modules>
  <properties> 
    <!-- NISX: These properties should never be changed. Only change the value of org.component.version. -->
    <org.assemble.my.version>${org.component.version.with.build.number}</org.assemble.my.version>
    <org.myportal.version>${org.component.version}</org.myportal.version>
    <org.myshare.version>${org.component.version}</org.myshare.version>
   ... + several others. shortened for stackoverflow
  </properties>


  <build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
      <!-- NISX: This is a trick to avoid the ghost pom to be ever deployed to a repository. -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>qdev-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org.qdev.plugin.version}</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <beaDeployDirectory>${qdev.deploy.dir}</beaDeployDirectory>
                    <earName>${qdev.ear.name}</earName>
                    <warName>${qdev.war.name}</warName> 
                    <isSingleWar>true</isSingleWar>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-udv-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <settingsApplicationName>my</settingsApplicationName>
                        <settingsApplicationVersion>${my.branch.name}</settingsApplicationVersion>
                        <settingsApplicationState>${profile.state}</settingsApplicationState>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The version you used `null:customer-ebpart:zip:${org.myportal.version}` does not work. Please show your pom files so we can give more detailed hints.

Comment: I'll retrieve the project's pom.xml, and the client-product-0.0.pom. let me know if there are any others that I need to get, to be able to get help. It's gonna take just a few minutes, as I anonymize them...

Comment: First why did you change the default folder layout? What's the reason? Where are those plugins comming from groupId: `org.maven.plugins` does not exist on maven central?

Comment: org.maven.plugins is really company-name.maven.plugins. They are custom company plugins. If I have changed the default folder layout, I am unaware of that I have. I am also not sure what consequences it gives. My only guess is that the folder layout might be changed due to some company setup, which might have automaticly set up through scripts. Or I have made a boo-boo.